# After Effects: Change Faux Italic Angle

Tags: fonts, adobe-after-effects

I have a font that I made myself, with a faux italic angled at 15 degrees. I have a text layer for a title card which uses the oblique version.
However, I only exported the upright version of the alternate glyphs, and the default slant After Effects gives is only at about 10 degrees. Is there a way to change the slant of the faux italic feature?

NOTE: For the time being, I'm just using the upright font with the "Animate: > Slant" option, but I need an alternate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO! Unfortunately. Faux bold and italic are pretty rigid things. You can use a slant or skew to distort to get a steeper angle, but it's a distortion, so not perfect.